# Why is Mapping not working after flattening an array of arrays

Tags: angular

I am trying to find out why flattening this array of arrays to an array of objects won't let me map it? If I change the array manually to an array of objects the mapping works fine. The flattening works as it does work in the multi-select dropdown I am using and wouldn't work until I flattened it.

The following code won't build, it says that the x.displayValue doesn't exist - when in fact it does.

```
import { Component, OnInit, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { IDropdownSettings } from 'ng-multiselect-dropdown';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-flatten-arrays',
  templateUrl: './flatten-arrays.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./flatten-arrays.component.css']
})
export class FlattenArraysComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  selectedInstitutions = [
    [{ displayValue: 'ABC', id: 781 }],
    [{ displayValue: 'DEF', id: 782 }],
  ];

  abbreviation = { institutionIds: 1 };

  transcriptSettings: IDropdownSettings = {
    singleSelection: false,
    idField: 'id',
    textField: 'displayValue',
    selectAllText: 'Select All',
    unSelectAllText: 'Unselect All',
    itemsShowLimit: 3,
    allowSearchFilter: true,
  };

  ngOnInit() {


    // this.selectedInstitutions = ([] as any[]).concat(...this.selectedInstitutions);
    this.selectedInstitutions = ([] as any[]).concat(...this.selectedInstitutions);

    const temp = this.selectedInstitutions.map(x => <any>{
      title: x.displayValue
    });

  }
}
```

I am just doing the mapping just for testing. But if I comment out the mapping code, it works fine - which is why I know it is flattened. But why does it say the x.displayValue doesn't exist. Is my mapping code incorrect? I am assuming this is now an array of objects.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this line,

```js
selectedInstitutions = [
  [{ displayValue: 'ABC', id: 781 }],
  [{ displayValue: 'DEF', id: 782 }],
];
```

the variable was declared as `any[][]` a.k.a Array of Array type.

Even you have flattened the array in `ngOnInit`, the variable is still as Array of Array type.

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.selectedInstitutions = ([] as any[]).concat(
    ...this.selectedInstitutions
  );
}
```

Hence, the `x` is an array instead of an object.

```js
const temp = this.selectedInstitutions.map(
  (x) =>
    <any>{
      title: x.displayValue,
    }
);
```

---

**Solution (but not suggested)**

For quick fixing, specify `x` as `any`.

But **NOT SUGGESTED** as the same issue (conflict in variable type) will *still happen when you do a similar logic like iterate with `selectedInstitutions`*.

```js
const temp = this.selectedInstitutions.map(
  (x: any) =>
    <any>{
      title: x.displayValue,
    }
);
```

**Solution**

1. Declaring another variable `institutions`, that hold the initial value (with `any[][]` type).
2. Flatten `institutions` and assign to `selectedInstitutions` (`any[]` type).
3. Use `selectedInstitutions` for the array iteration.

```js
selectedInstitutions: any[];

institutions = [
  [{ displayValue: 'ABC', id: 781 }],
  [{ displayValue: 'DEF', id: 782 }],
];

ngOnInit() {
  this.selectedInstitutions = ([] as any[]).concat(
    ...this.institutions
  );

  const temp = this.selectedInstitutions.map(
    (x: any) =>
      <any>{
        title: x.displayValue,
      }
  );
}
```

[Sample Demo on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gdhvmg?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Actually, you don't seem to need the (x: any) for it to work. But you do need the <any> after the arrow.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the optimal solution but to me it worked by adding an explicit return keyword:

```
const temp = this.selectedInstitutions.map(x => {
    return <any>{
      title: x.displayValue
    }
});
```

I tried this code in the browser console using your selectedInstitutions array and it worked:

```
let flatenned = [].concat(...selectedInstitutions)
let mapped = flatenned.map(x => { return { title: x.displayValue}})
```

Comment: That format of flattening only works for me if I have StrickNullChecks off.